# Update a complex JSONB object to remove a sub-sub-property with a PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Assuming I have JSONB data like this in a column `my_jsonb` PostgreSQL database table with the following pattern:

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "bar": [
        {
          "baz": 1,
          "qux": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "bar": [
        {
          "baz": 3,
          "qux": 4
        },
        {
          "baz": 5,
          "qux": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

In other words, each column `my_jsonb` has a list of `foo` that has a property `bar` that contains an array of objects with two properties `baz` and `qux`.

I now consider that `baz` property is obsolete, I would like to remove it to have this:

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "bar": [
        {
          "qux": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "bar": [
        {
          "qux": 4
        },
        {
          "qux": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I could delete these `baz` properties one by one in each `bar` item with a script but it would be super long. Is there a way to update a complex JSONB object to remove a sub-sub-property without doing something with a script?

*It's OK to do it row by row (there are only 100k rows in my actual table, so I consider it's safe to iterate each row, the only thing I want is **to remove all `baz` properties in a row at once**).*

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases the json structure is rigid, you are able to recreate json objects in a way like this:

```
select id, jsonb_agg(new_foos order by fo)
from (
    select 
        id, fo, 
        jsonb_build_object(
            'foo', 
            jsonb_build_object(
                'bar', 
                jsonb_agg(bars- 'baz' order by bo))
        ) as new_foos
    from my_table
    cross join 
        jsonb_array_elements(json_data) 
        with ordinality as foos(foos, fo)
    cross join 
        jsonb_array_elements(foos->'foo'->'bar') 
        with ordinality as bars(bars, bo)
    group by id, fo
    ) s
group by id
```

Note that we use aggregates with the order got by `with ordinality` feature to preserve the original order of arrays elements.

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=376b928be97a9e9311f5c0c23c28db2b)

Comment: One more question: is the order guaranteed in both arrays?

Comment: Thank you so much again! Maybe you could update your post by adding the "alternate" version with order preserved after the original one? It could help other readers to find an appropriate solution. I could also do it myself if you prefer. Thank you!